# Substituting Lard for Soy Shortening

Tags: baking

how do I convert my cake recipes from shortening to lard-I live at 6000 ft altitude. The lard is hydrogenated and has more water so it needs adjustment. I'm at altitude and that requires adjustments which I can do. BUT do I use the same amount of lard as shortening as listed in the recipe?

Comment: Another thing you might consider is coconut oil or [soy-free shortening](http://www.amazon.com/Spectrum-Organic-Shortening-24/dp/B004WOMWWE)

Comment: I edited your title to make it clearer what the question was about. I have some other questions though: Is this plain lard that you're using? How does it have more water in it?

Comment: I'd just suggest replacing the fat for fat in equal amounts. If required you can just modify the recipe next time round.

Comment: Can you clarify your statement that the lard "has more water"?

Comment: Yeah, lard and shortening should be about the same... and will probably taste better. Butter certainly has more water content than lard. Also... shortening in cakes? This is new to me. Every recipe I've done uses butter.